# Error in starting confluent in Ubuntu. confluent requires curl

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have installed confluent 3.3.1 in Ubuntu 16.04LTS. I followed all the instructions to install confluent as per documentation. But, when I start confluent using "confluent start". I am getting an error 'confluent' requires 'curl'. What should I change to fix this issue. I have Java8 and Scala 2.11 in my system.

This is the link i followed.

[Install Confluent 3.3.1](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp.html#debian-and-ubuntu)

[image: confluent error screen]

Answer (score 0):

just install `curl` package via

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

it could be that they don't have dependency explicitly set in their package - it's better to raise a bug...

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to track https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-cli/issues/54

It'll be fixed in the forthcoming bugfix release for each version of Confluent Platform.

Answer (score 0):

I still get this error on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo) as of May 22nd 2018.

The solution as mentioned by Alex Ott is to install curl.

`sudo yum install curl`